# Performance Boosting C++

Tags: c++, performance, algorithm, memory

Here is my code below.

```
Point3* LASReader::GetPoint(int index)
{
    if (m_index == m_header.NPointRecords)
        return 0;

stream.seekg(GetOffset(index));
m_index++;

LASPOINTF1 p0;
LASPOINTF1 p1;
LASPOINTF2 p2;
LASPOINTF3 p3;
LASPOINTF4 p4;
LASPOINTF5 p5;
Vector3 position;

// Get the point values
switch (m_header.PointDataFormat)
{
case 0:
    stream.read((char *)&p0, sizeof(LASPOINTF0));
    position = Vector3(p0.X, p0.Y, p0.Z);
    break;
case 1:
    stream.read((char *)&p1, sizeof(LASPOINTF1));
    position = Vector3(p1.X, p1.Y, p1.Z);
    break;
case 2:
    stream.read((char *)&p2, sizeof(LASPOINTF2));
    position = Vector3(p2.X, p2.Y, p2.Z);
    break;
case 3:
    stream.read((char *)&p3, sizeof(LASPOINTF3));
    position = Vector3(p3.X, p3.Y, p3.Z);
    break;
case 4:
    stream.read((char *)&p4, sizeof(LASPOINTF4));
    position = Vector3(p4.X, p4.Y, p4.Z);
    break;
case 5:
    stream.read((char *)&p5, sizeof(LASPOINTF5));
    position = Vector3(p5.X, p5.Y, p5.Z);
    break;
}


// Calculate the real coordinates of the point
position = position * *m_scale + *m_offset;

return new Point3(position.GetX(), position.GetY(), position.GetZ());
}

// Main

int main()
{
    VertexPosColF* pcmVertices = new VertexPosColF[reader->GetHeader().NPointRecords];
    while (!reader->AllPointsRead())
{
    pcmVertices[i].Position = reader->GetPoint()->GetPosition()->GetD3DXVECTOR3();
    pcmVertices[i].Color = D3DXVECTOR4(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    i++;
}
}
```

And here is my problem. I'm reading a file using a method like GetFromFile() (it is not enough I know but it is a sample only), maybe I'm calling it milion times so the if else conditions running million times. I want it called one time before the method called. how can i handle the different types? The switch case block must not be called million times I think.

My second problem is when I called GetFromFile method million times there is a lot of memory allocation about 4gbs. In my original code A, B,... structures' total size is nearly 200-300 byte and when I called the GetFromFile method 20.000.000 times I can see clearly there is 5GBs of memory allocation. Why? When the method finishes, are structures A a, and B b mustn't be released from memory? They are not pointers so I cannot delete manually.

It is a las file contains point cloud which rendered using DirectX.
edit: Updated code and explanation

Comment: This code cannot be compiled. There are no allocations here. Structs A and P are identical. All together looks a bit strange...

Comment: There is no need to be compiled is there? All of the code is just a sample. If it is not clear or any other problem, I can explain my problem more.

Comment: @Cahit Burak Küçüksütcü: You really want to post a [short, self-contained, compilable example](http://www.sscce.org/) that reproduces the problem, especially when we're talking about performance. If we can't even run it, we can't help. It's like bringing a plastic model of your car to the mechanic instead of your actual car when something is wrong.

Comment: well you posted a code which won't have problems with memory allocation yet you expect us to solve your problem... obviously we need code which can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Well, petersohn fixed your compilation errors... You can write two functions: GetFromFileA and GetFromFileB. Test file_is_A_formatted once and then call GetFromFileA or GetFromFileB million times.

Comment: Ok, I'm going to post my original code shortly

Comment: @Alex Farber: Ok it is clear but in the main method I must use only one method. Because there are 6 different formats. But in the reader class i can use a lot of private reader method GetFromFileA, B, C...

Comment: maybe some problems are occurring with the conversion in `stream.read((char*)&a, sizeof(A);`, that conversion from `A &` to `char *`.. Yet, some more code is needed.

Comment: Millions of invocations of `switch` are unlikely to be your performance bottleneck (compared to, say, millions of invocations of `new`). Modern CPUs are pretty good at predicting branches, especially when they go the same way millions of times in a row. As always, profiling is the only way to be sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a start, in...

```
pcmVertices[i].Position = reader->GetPoint()->GetPosition()->GetD3DXVECTOR3();
```

...you call `GetPoint()` which returns a newly dynamically allocated object, but you keep no reference to the pointer with which to `delete` it.  If you say change from...

```
Point3* LASReader::GetPoint(int index)
```

...to either of...

```
Point3 LASReader::GetPoint(int index)  // ALSO remove "new" from GetPoint's return

std::unique_ptr<Point3> LASReader::GetPoint(int index)
```

...the memory deallocation will take care of itself relatively efficiently.  Unless `GetD3DXVECTOR3` is returning a reference or pointer to anything inside the `Point3` object... if that's the case, then you better keep the objects hanging around - saving the pointers from `GetPoint` somewhere first.

It would also be more typical C++ to change `pcmVertices` to...

```
std::vector<VertexPosColF> pcmVertices(reader->GetHeader().NPointRecords);
```

...which ensures the `VertexPosCoLF` destructors run when `pcmVertices` goes out of scope, then initialise as in...

```
for (int i = 0; !reader->AllPointsRead(); ++i)
{
    VertexPosColF v;
    v.Position = reader->GetPoint()->GetPosition()->GetD3DXVECTOR3();
    v.Color = D3DXVECTOR4(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    pcmVertices.push_back(v);
}
```

Comment: Ok. I understand and it solved my memory problem but why the destructor of Point3 is not running here:
pcmVertices[i].Position = reader->GetPoint()->GetPosition()->GetD3DXVECTOR3();

Comment: The purpose of `new` is to return memory that outlives the function call returning it... that's why the destructor isn't invoked and the memory isn't released.  My advice is to try to avoid `new` as much as possible, and use Standard containers and return-by-value unless performance forces you to do otherwise, then reach for smart pointers (unique_ptr, shared_ptr, weak_ptr) if you have boost or C++11.

Comment: Ok. These answers are really helped me. I think I need to do some practicing about C++. I know what the pointer is but in practive I'm confusing.

Comment: @CahitBurakKüçüksütcü: I think it will probably save you time and grief in the medium term.  Good luck!

Comment: Btw, Which one must I prefer. Windows API like Get(point3* p) or Point3 Get()? I know first one is usefult for getting multiple values. Is there any other issues?

Comment: Returning objects by value is usually what you want. `Point3 Get()` is easier to read than `Get(Point3*)` and (usually) just as fast thanks to Return Value Optimization. Also it allows you to write things like `const Point3 p = Get()`, which is good style and also easy to read

Comment: @CahitBurakKüçüksütcü: Nemo's right. `std::vector<Point3> get() const` and `void get(std::vector<Point3>&) const` can be good too, when you want to return multiple objects you just `push_back` without doing `new` yourself or needing complicated ownership conventions with the caller. You can return `bool` to indicate success/failure if it works out better in your app than exceptions. Just a suggestion - I like to call a function "load" if it loads results into parameters, where-as "get" returns the value of interest: that can minimise confusion and make calling code more self-documenting.

Answer (score 1):

If you can put your method as member of an object you could do something like that (pseudo code)

```
 class PLoaderInterface 
 {
      virtual P GetFromFile();
 }
```

Create 2 class LoaderA and LoaderB based on that interface

in the constructor of LoaderA and LoaderB 
preload everything in array of P(struct P seem equal to A) and in array of B

Now create a kind of factory

```
   PLoaderIntetface GetLoader(string filename);
```

where depending of your file type you allocate on type or the other !

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can avoid the if statement, but if that's just a checking of a bool variable, then it doesn't have much performance impact. You may improve performance somewhat by declaring `a` and `b` only in the scope where it is required.

```
P GetFromFile()
{
   P p;

   if(file_is_A_formatted) {
      A a;
      stream.read((char*)&a, sizeof(A));
      p.x = a.x;
      p.y = a.y;
   }
   else {
      B b;
      stream.read((char*)&b, sizeof(B));
      p.x = b.x;
      p.y = b.y + b.z;
   }

  return p;
}
```

If you have memory leaks though, that's somewhere else in your code because this code shouldn't leak. Of course your code contains a lot of syntactic errors, but I guess that it's just something you typed in here.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I'll return shortly.